# NetLogo: Changing a certain percentage of patches a certain color

Tags: netlogo

I would like to create an environment with three different patch colors. On the interface, I would like to be able have three sliders that allow me to control the percentage of each patch color that gets created. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you having trouble setting up the sliders or actually coloring the patches?

Comment: Suppose each slider were set to 1/3. Is your requirement that you get _exactly_ 1/3 of each color _every_ time, or do you just want each patch to roll the dice independently and have a 1/3 chance of being each color? These are different requirements requiring different code. The latter choice is easier to code, so if you don't know or care which you want, go with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have three sliders named slider1, slider2, and slider3 this code will do what I believe you are asking:

```
to color-patches 
  let total slider1 + slider2 + slider3
  let p-red   slider1 / total
  let p-green slider2 / total
  let p-blue  slider3 / total

  ask patches [
    let x random-float 1.0
    if x <= p-red + p-green + p-blue [set pcolor blue]
    if x <= p-red + p-green [set pcolor green]
    if x <= p-red [set pcolor red]
  ]
end
```

If all sliders have the same range (e.g., 0 to 100) the amount of red, green, and blue will be proportional to the relative position of all three sliders. If all sliders are set to the same value you will get approximately 1/3 of each color. Of course we are using random numbers here, so it is possible to get strange results.